# Use .htaccess to load files from another folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a good reason to do this. I feel this is the most cost effective way of providing an update.

This is my current url structure

```
/ <-- Contains Website
/cart
/cms
```

Boss wants the client to have an option to forego the website and instead load the cart in place of the website. The system is fairly old, the website and cart are completely different systems. We host a lot of websites from this single system. Configuring 2 systems for 2 different websites types will involve too much maintenence.

The least work solution would be to rewrite the /cart into /. I came up with the following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cart/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cart/$1
```

This returns a server error. Adding `/cart/$1` on the final line does work. I need this to work when the system isn't installed in the root directory. **Does anyone know how to fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(cart|cms)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}cart/$1 [L]
```